# Use of どこ in this sentence

Tags: words, syntax, questions

Context: a girl is waiting for the speaker walking around an airport.

> アレじゃ待ってんのか牽制されてるのか分からんし

I don't have a clue about what is she waiting for, neither what is she checking,

> ……しかも何度か目が合ったのに**どこ**吹く風で。

... even when our eyes repeatedly make contact where (?) the wind blows (so wind blows according to their glances?)

Is どこ even used without a question context?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a set phrase. See [jisho's definition](https://jisho.org/word/どこ吹く風). Looks like the person is behaving as if he (she?) hadn't noticed the other person.

Comment: That was said in a meeting after years or something but the characters are really weird, the speaker right after this says "Heey, so long time!!!". Regarding the sentence, yeah, now it makes sense as for even with the glances nothing was happened.